# associated type `BlockNumber` not found for `T`

Tags: pallet

I am following following tutorial to write a custom pallet.

https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/build-application-logic/use-macros-in-a-custom-pallet/

When I compile the node, I get following error:

```rs
error[E0220]: associated type `BlockNumber` not found for `T`
  --> pallets/template/src/lib.rs:46:62
   |
46 |         StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::Hash, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber)>;
   |                                                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^ there is a similarly named associated type `BlockNumber` in the trait `BlockNumberProvider`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0220`.
```

Here are the contents of my pallet lib.rs file that I trying to compile:

```rs
    #![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]
    
    // Re-export pallet items so that they can be accessed from the crate namespace.
    pub use pallet::*;
    
    #[frame_support::pallet]
    pub mod pallet {
        use frame_support::pallet_prelude::*;
        use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;
    
        #[pallet::pallet]
        #[pallet::generate_store(pub(super) trait Store)]
        
        pub struct Pallet<T>(_);
    
        /// Configure the pallet by specifying the parameters and types on which it depends.
        #[pallet::config]
        pub trait Config: frame_system::Config {
            /// Because this pallet emits events, it depends on the runtime's definition of an event.
            type RuntimeEvent: From<Event<Self>> + IsType<<Self as frame_system::Config>::RuntimeEvent>;
        }
    
        // Pallets use events to inform users when important changes are made.
        // Event documentation should end with an array that provides descriptive names for parameters.
        #[pallet::event]
        #[pallet::generate_deposit(pub(super) fn deposit_event)]
        pub enum Event<T: Config> {
            /// Event emitted when a claim has been created.
            ClaimCreated { who: T::AccountId, claim: T::Hash },
            /// Event emitted when a claim is revoked by the owner.
            ClaimRevoked { who: T::AccountId, claim: T::Hash },
        }
    
        #[pallet::error]
        pub enum Error<T> {
            /// The claim already exists.
            AlreadyClaimed,
            /// The claim does not exist, so it cannot be revoked.
            NoSuchClaim,
            /// The claim is owned by another account, so caller can't revoke it.
            NotClaimOwner,
        }
    
        #[pallet::storage]
        pub(super) type Claims<T: Config> =
            StorageMap<_, Blake2_128Concat, T::Hash, (T::AccountId, T::BlockNumber)>;
    
        // Dispatchable functions allow users to interact with the pallet and invoke state changes.
        // These functions materialize as "extrinsics", which are often compared to transactions.
        // Dispatchable functions must be annotated with a weight and must return a DispatchResult.
        #[pallet::call]
        impl<T: Config> Pallet<T> {
            #[pallet::weight(0)]
            pub fn create_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
                // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
                // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
                let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    
                // Verify that the specified claim has not already been stored.
                ensure!(!Claims::<T>::contains_key(&claim), Error::<T>::AlreadyClaimed);
    
                // Get the block number from the FRAME System pallet.
                let current_block = <frame_system::Pallet<T>>::block_number();
    
                // Store the claim with the sender and block number.
                Claims::<T>::insert(&claim, (&sender, current_block));
    
                // Emit an event that the claim was created.
                Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimCreated { who: sender, claim });
    
                Ok(())
            }
    
            #[pallet::weight(0)]
            pub fn revoke_claim(origin: OriginFor<T>, claim: T::Hash) -> DispatchResult {
                // Check that the extrinsic was signed and get the signer.
                // This function will return an error if the extrinsic is not signed.
                let sender = ensure_signed(origin)?;
    
                // Get owner of the claim, if none return an error.
                let (owner, _) = Claims::<T>::get(&claim).ok_or(Error::<T>::NoSuchClaim)?;
    
                // Verify that sender of the current call is the claim owner.
                ensure!(sender == owner, Error::<T>::NotClaimOwner);
    
                // Remove claim from storage.
                Claims::<T>::remove(&claim);
    
                // Emit an event that the claim was erased.
                Self::deposit_event(Event::ClaimRevoked { who: sender, claim });
                Ok(())
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Check https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/commit/5e7b27e98c0b9dacd4b6f0724fd6335106d94101.

Now, you should use `BlockNumberFor<T>` directly. Because you have already imported it with `use frame_system::pallet_prelude::*;`.

Comment: Dear Aurevioc, 

Thank for the help

What I understand is, there is some made to the code base but the tutorial are  not yet adjusted accordingly. Since I am facing the very same issue in an other tutorial as well. But I am still not very sure how to  use BlockNumberFor<T> in place of BlockNumber<T>.

Comment: You simply need to replace any occurrence of `T::BlockNumber` with `BlockNumberFor<T>`. This is primarily a Rust-related matter. As `BlockNumber` is no longer a part of `T`, it has been moved to the `Header` within `T`. Additionally, they have introduced a type alias called `BlockNumberFor`, which corresponds to `<HeaderFor<T> as Header>::Number`. Essentially, this is equivalent to writing something like `T::Header::Number`.

Comment: It still gives the following error:

 type CollectionRandomness: frame_support::traits::Randomness<Self::Hash, BlockNumberFor<T>>;
   |                                                                                                 ^ not found in this scope

Comment: Without the context, I can't help you.

Comment: Here is the github link please:

https://github.com/sayyedkamran/substrate-node-template/blob/add_pallet_collectibles/pallets/collectibles/src/lib.rs

Comment: Within this context, there is no `T`. We use `T` to represent `Config` everywhere else. However, in this case, we directly use `Self` in the definition. So, `Randomness<Self::Hash, BlockNumberFor<Self>>` should suffice.

Comment: Thank you very much @Aurevoir for the help. It get compiled. 

I am just asking for the benefit of the community and my knowledge, do you think, there is a need to upgrade the tutorial at substrate.io?